# How to use superputty file transfer context menu?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, context-menu, superputty

I am using superputty version 1.3.0.11 under windows 10.
In superputty  , I go to the sessions-> Putty Session -> Right click on the one of the sessions and select "File Transfer" from the context menu. [image]

I see the new tab for the server as sown in the picture above.
How to navigate to the folders on the servers and copy paste from linux server (listed under putty session) to local windows 10 machine.
If I drag and drop file from window 10 desktop to this opened session, I get something like below:
[image]

But the file transfer never happens. Do you know what am I missing here and how can I fix the problem? Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

You need write access to the directory you want to copy your files to. You can check that e.g. with

```
ls -l -a
```

output will look like shown below.

```
username@machine:~$ ls -l -a
insgesamt 1336
drwxr-xr-x 9 username usergroup    4096  Mär 15 20:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root          4096  Okt 15  2015 ..
-rw------- 1 username usergroup    33899 Mär 16 11:44 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 username usergroup    220   Okt 15  2015 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 username usergroup    3637  Okt 15  2015 .bashrc
```

first row with the "." in the end stands for the current directory. In the first column you can see "drwxr-xr-x", meaning:

```
d: it is a directory
r: file (directory) owner has read access
w: file (directory) owner has write access
x: file (directory) owner can execute
r: file (directory) group has read access
-: file (directory) group has NO write access
x: file (directory) group can execute
r: all other have read access
-: all other have NO write access
x: all other can execute
```

In a quite normal setup you should have write access to your home directory.
You can change there by typing `cd ~`. Then try to copy your file to this location.

Comment: thanks for your time. But I already have read write execute access to the folder. I think its something related to windows 10 , not sure.